# Magic Leap / WebRTC

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, webrtc, fieldofview, magic-leap

I need to transmit via WebRTC the field of view of the magic Leap and not the external video camera of the ML. Does anyone know if there is anything actively from ML and WebRTC to solve this problem?